# Google Cloud Load Balancer vs Nginx Load Balancer Are they different?

Tags: node.js, nginx, google-compute-engine

I have a node.js application on Google CE (compute engine) that is running behind a nginx server.

Should I be using nginx load balancer and Google Cloud load balancer?

Or are they the same?

Or should I use just one?

If they are different, what are the differences?

Answer (score 3):

Nginx has more options but you have to manage it yourself. You have also to make sure that your machine supports the highest load of the day.

Google Cloud Load Balancer works well but has less options (it has only one algorithm: 5-tuple hashing (source IP, destination IP, source Port, destination Port, protocol) to distribute the load)

We switched from Nginx to GCLB to sleep better at night.